# Problema al copiar archivos

Tags: c

tengo un programa que copia archivos de un directorios pero me genera problema copiando archivos que no sean txt, para testear uso imágenes y mp4 que tenia ya guardados en mi pc por facilidad. Al intentar copiar una imagen se crea un archivo .jpg que pesa 1KB en comparación a los 149KB que pesa el original. Este problema solo me ocurre en windows en linux funciona perfecto

```
void Copiar(char *File_Name, char Ruta_Pendrive[200] , char Ruta_Guardado[200]){

char Ruta_Pendrive_Copia[200];
char Ruta_Guardado_Base[200];

strcpy( Ruta_Guardado_Base, Ruta_Guardado );
strcpy( Ruta_Pendrive_Copia, Ruta_Pendrive );

strcat( Ruta_Pendrive_Copia, File_Name );
strcat( Ruta_Guardado_Base, File_Name );

FILE *file1 = fopen( Ruta_Guardado_Base , "w" );
if( file1 == NULL ){
    printf("  [!!] No se puedo abrir el archivo de escritura. \n" );
}
FILE *file2 = fopen( Ruta_Pendrive_Copia , "r" );
if( file2 == NULL ){
    printf("  [!!] No se puedo abrir el archivo de Lectura. \n" );
}

int x;
while(!feof(file2)){
    x = fgetc(file2);
    fputc(x, file1);
}

printf( "Listo. \n" );

fclose( file1 );
fclose( file2 );
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Prueba a abrir ambos ficheros (escritura y lectura) en modo binario, usando los modos `"wb"` y `"rb"` respectivamente.

Comment: Wow... me siento como un idiota, de hecho pensé que ya había probado eso porque lo había dejado en un comentario... @abulafia muchas gracias